# The second Tate-Shafarevich group of a permutation module is trivial

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, group-cohomology, galois-cohomology, global-fields, tate-shafarevich-groups

Suppose I have a global field $K$ and a finite Galois extension $L/K$ of Galois group $G$. It is often written without proofs (it seems that this is a very common statement) that for every $G$-module $M$ of permutation (that is a free $\mathbf{Z}$-module that admits a basis permuted by the action of $G$), the Tate-Shafarevich group of degree $2$
$$ \mathrm{Sha}^2(G,M)=\mathrm{Ker}\left(H^2(G,M)\longrightarrow\prod_{v\in\Omega_K}H^2(G_v,M)\right) $$
where $\Omega_K$ is the set of places of $K$ and $G_v=\mathrm{Gal}(L_w/K_v)$ for $w$ a place of $L$ that extends $v$, is trivial. Do you have any reference for this ? or a proof (if it's not too long) ?

Comment: For the MO community, please state clearly the desired assertion.  What is a permutation module?  What do you mean by $\rm Sha$?  $\rm Sha^1$ or $\rm Sha^2$?  Is the extension $L/K$ finite or infinite? After that I will type a proof or give a reference.

Comment: I've added more context to my question.

Comment: See Lemma 1.9  of J.-J. Sansuc,  Groupe de Brauer et arithmétique des groupes algébriques linéaires sur un corps de nombres, J. Reine Angew. Math. 327 (1981), 12–80.

Comment: Idea of proof: (1) You may assume that $M={\mathbb Z}$. (2)  We have $$H^2(G,{\mathbb Z})\cong H^1(G,{\mathbb Q}/{\mathbb Z})={\rm Hom}(G, {\mathbb Q}/{\mathbb Z}).$$ (3) You use the Chebotarev density theorem: for any cyclic subgroup $H\subseteq G$ there exists $v$ and $w$ such that ${\rm Gal}(L_w/K_v)=H$. The lemma follows.

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi, aren't [1](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/449884/tate-shafarevich-group-of-a-permutation-module-is-trivial#comment1162589_449884) and [2](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/449884/tate-shafarevich-group-of-a-permutation-module-is-trivial#comment1162595_449884) together an answer?

Comment: @LSpice: Yes, they are.  I will type an answer when I have time, hopefully tomorrow.

Comment: @LSpice:  I have typed an answer. It is not just two comments!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We write $G_w={\rm Gal}(L_w/K_v)$.

> **Definition.**  For $n\ge 1$, we denote
> $$Ш_\omega^n(G,M)=\ker\Big(H^n(G,M)\to\prod_C H^n(C,M)\Big)$$
> where $C$ runs over the cyclic subgroups of $G$.

> **Remark.** $Ш^2(L/K,M)\subseteq Ш_\omega^2(G, M)$. Indeed,
> by the  Chebotarev density theorem, for any cyclic subgroup $C\subseteq G$
> there exist $v$ and $w$ such that $G_w=C$.

> **Definition.** A permutation $G$-module is a torsion free $G$-module admitting a $G$-invariant (as a subset) ${\mathbb Z}$-basis $B$.

> **Theorem.** If $M$ is a permutation $G$-module, then $Ш_\omega^2(G,M)=0$, and therefore $Ш^2(L/K,M)=0$.

*Sketch of proof.*

*Step 1.*
We have
$$ Ш_\omega^2(G,M_1\oplus M_2)=Ш_\omega^2(G,M_1) \oplusШ_\omega^2(G, M_2),$$
which reduces the theorem to the case when $G$ acts on the basis $B$ transitively.
Then using Shapiro's lemma we reduce the theorem to the case $M={\mathbb Z}$ (with trivial $G$-action).

*Step 2.* We have a short exact sequence of $G$-modules (with trivial $G$-action)
$$0\to {\mathbb Z}\to{\mathbb Q}\to {\mathbb Q}/{\mathbb Z}\to 0,$$
which gives rise to cohomology exact sequences
\begin{align*}
&0= H^1(G,{\mathbb Q})\to H^1(G,{\mathbb Q}/{\mathbb Z}) \to H^2(G,{\mathbb Z})\to H^2(G,{\mathbb Q})=0\\
&0= H^1(C,{\mathbb Q})\to H^1(C,{\mathbb Q}/{\mathbb Z}) \to H^2(C,{\mathbb Z})\to H^2(C,{\mathbb Q})=0.
\end{align*}
Therefore, we may identify
$$Ш_\omega^2(G,{\mathbb Z})=Ш_\omega^1(G,{\mathbb Q}/{\mathbb Z}),$$
and it suffices to show that $Ш_\omega^1(G,{\mathbb Q}/{\mathbb Z})=0$.
By definition,
$H^1(G,{\mathbb Q}/{\mathbb Z})={\rm Hom}(G,{\mathbb Q}/{\mathbb Z})$ and $H^1(C,{\mathbb Q}/{\mathbb Z})={\rm Hom}(C,{\mathbb Q}/{\mathbb Z})$.
It remain to show that
$$\ker\Big({\rm Hom}(G,{\mathbb Q}/{\mathbb Z})\to \prod_C{\rm Hom}(C,{\mathbb Q}/{\mathbb Z})\Big)=0,$$
but this is obvious because $G$ is the union of its cyclic subgroups $C$.

*Reference:* Lemma 1.9 of J.-J. Sansuc, Groupe de Brauer et arithmétique des groupes algébriques linéaires sur un corps de nombres, J. Reine Angew. Math. 327 (1981), 12–80.